# How to fetch data from yaml to any other JS file

Tags: javascript, node.js, gcloud

Im deploying my node app on google cloud platform and i want to store my mysql username, password and db name in the yaml file which will be the same used in gcloud and i want to use the same values to come into my another file database.js which is in different folder. How to active this.

[image: to show the file hierarchy]

[image: my current app.yaml file]

and i want to get the username and password from app.yaml to database.js.
Thankyou in advance for the help. :D

Comment: Don't store your private information in a file, instead use environment variables. They are easier and safer to use. Read [Node.js Everywhere with Environment Variables!](https://medium.com/the-node-js-collection/making-your-node-js-work-everywhere-with-environment-variables-2da8cdf6e786) on Medium. See [Using Environment Variables](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/env-var) in Google Cloud.

Comment: There's a yaml package on [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yaml) which you can use to parse the file and get the values.

Comment: @CarloCorradini funny enough, in the medium article they also recommend to keep the data in a `.env` file which to me seems just like yaml file just different syntax.

Comment: @CarloCorradini The most important thing is to avoid storing secrets (passwords, etc) in files which get committed to source control. Using a yaml file is OK if your `.gitignore` contains a line saying `*.yaml` or some such thing.

Comment: @ShivanSharma take a look at the npm package called config (https://www.npmjs.com/package/config).  It may be more than you need for your application, but it lets you build a robust setup for configuring your node applications. Including yaml files.

Comment: @Molda I have explained why storing secrets in a file is really bad practice in a production environment. An article about env variables is better than a random comment on stackoverflow. The .env is commonly used for testing purposes and ignored since it's listed in the .gitignore file. So before deploying the app on Google Cloud set the enviroment variables via console and the magic happens. This is the best and secure practice.

Comment: @O.Jones You are right but he explicitly wrote that Database username and password must be stored. As far as I can see the other variable he want to store is the node version so env is good enough :\

Answer (score 0):

You can specify additional environment variables in `app.yaml`:

```
env_variables:
  MY_VAR: "my value"
```

In your case `app.yaml` would look something like this:

```
runtime:nodejs10
env_variables:
      USERNAME: "my username"
      PASSWORD: "secret"
```

In Node.js, you can use the environment like this:

```
const username = process.env.USERNAME;
```